# Chrome - Suppress the extra "Save Password" Prompt

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Chrome to sign in to work remotely.  Chrome does save the username/password by default.  That part works fine.  After this sign in, it prompts for a security code that comes via email.

When I enter the security code Chrome prompts to save password again.

**Is there any technique to suppress that second save password prompt?**

My Google-fu has been unsuccessful.  The overwhelming majority of hits relate how to enable and disable the save username/password setting.

My expectation is that there ought to be a setting to suppress this behavior.
Failing that, pointing my nose at existing documentation, or giving suggestions for effectively researching the issue are gleefully accepted.